# Why my algorithm is using not a linear memory space?

Tags: typescript, algorithm, recursion, functional-programming

I'm currently writing this roll equality checking algorithm just for fun, the main goal is to do it declaratively and in functional style. Somehow my algorithm uses non-linear memory-space. In fact, it cannot run due to RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. Would be glad to get help from you:

```
const roll = (a: number): ((b: number) => number[]) => (b: number):  number[] => {
  let a1 = a * Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  let b1 = b * Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  return [a1, b1]
};

const compare = () => {
  let counter: number = 0;
  let totalcounter: number = 10000;
  const compareStep = (a: number[]) => {
    (() => (a[0] === 1 || a[1] === 1) && counter++)();
    totalcounter -= 1;
    (totalcounter === 0) ? console.log(counter / 10000) : compareStep(roll(1)(1));
  };
  return compareStep(roll(1)(1))
}

let Compare = compare();

Compare
```

Comment: When a function calls itself recursively, it needs to provide arguments that are closer to the base case. But you're generating a new set of rolls in every recursive call to `compareStep()`

Comment: doesn't my ```totalCounter``` decrement help?

Comment: You're allowing 10K recursions, that might be too many.

Comment: Is the idea that you want to see how many attempts it takes to get the same roll?

Comment: seems to me you're right, so I will try optimizing my algorithm. Ty!

Comment: `(() => (a[0] === 1 || a[1] === 1) && counter++)();` seems to be taking FP a bit too far. Why do you use an IIFE for that line, but not `totalcounter -= 1;`?

Comment: Ah, you're not stopping when you get a match. You're counting how many matches you get in 10k repetitions. You can't use recursion as a general substitute for iteration unless the language has tail recursion optimization.

Comment: Languages that are designed for FP do this, but most procedural languages don't.

Comment: then got to go learn Haskell:) Thank you anyway, I'm just really inspired with the ideas of FP and willing to learn it, but the only language I know good enough right now is JS/TS. Have a great day, sir!

Comment: You can do plenty of FP in JS.  But heavy recursion will be a problem for the foreseeable future.